# Problemas para recorrer NodeList y HtmlElement

Tags: javascript, html, css, animación

Estoy haciendo una animación con swiper, y un texto que se desliza con animate.css, tengo el siguiente Carrousel.

```
<section class="carousel">
        <h2 class="titcarousel">Empedrado</h2>
        <div class="swiper mySwiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/images/home/Carousel/foto-01.jpg" alt="">
                    <div id="textoimagen" class="textoimagen animate__slower animate__animated animate__fadeInLeftBig">
                        <h2>Dúplex Flama</h2>
                        <p>El Mejor Lugar Para Pasar tus Vacaciones...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/images/home/Carousel/foto-02.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/images/home/Carousel/foto-03.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="textoimagen animate__animated animate__fadeInLeftBig animate__slower">
                        <h2>El Camping Municipal</h2>
                        <p>Conocé el Camping Municipal Gerónimo Merello...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/images/home/Carousel/foto-04.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="textoimagen animate__animated animate__fadeInLeftBig animate__slower">
                        <h2>Pesca Deportiva</h2>
                        <p>Al borde del Rio Paraná...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/images/home/Carousel/foto-05.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/images/home/Carousel/foto-06.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="textoimagen animate__animated animate__fadeInLeftBig animate__slower">
                        <h2>La Vieja Estación</h2>
                        <p>Visita El Museo en La Antigua Estación de tren...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/images/home/Carousel/foto-07.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/images/home/Carousel/foto-08.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="textoimagen animate__animated animate__fadeInLeftBig animate__slower">
                        <h2>El Señor Hallado</h2>
                        <p>Visita La Antigua Iglesia de Empedrado...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary">Conocé Su Historia</button>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Lo que hago con un ID es frenar la animacion esperar unos segundos y volverla a iniciar.

```
<script>
    var textoimagen = document.getElementById('textoimagen');
     textoimagen.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
         textoimagen.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeInLeftBig');
            setTimeout(() => {
                textoimagen.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeInLeftBig');
            }, 2000);
     });
</script>
```

Ahora esto lo estoy haciendo con n id en uno de los div, el problema es cuando quero agregarle la animacion a todos los div clase textoimagen al mismo tiempo.

```
var textoimg = document.querySelectorAll('div.textoimagen');
```

obtengo un NodeList, que no conozco la manera de recorrerlo y agregarle el mismo efecto a cada divs en una sola funcion. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes recorrer la lista como si fuera un array:

```
var textoimgList = document.querySelectorAll('div.textoimagen');

textoimgList.forEach(textoimg => {
  textoimagen.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
    textoimagen.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeInLeftBig');
    setTimeout(() => {
      textoimagen.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeInLeftBig');
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```